# Converting Tuple inside of an array into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

I have been trying to solve this problem but I cannot get it right :(
I am querying mySQL database in Django, and my results comes back as a tuple inside of an array. Please see dummy data below;

```
query_results = [
    (500, datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)),
    (302, datetime.date(2017, 1, 2)),
    (550, datetime.date(2017, 1, 3)),
    (180, datetime.date(2017, 1, 4)),
    (645, datetime.date(2017, 1, 5)),
    (465, datetime.date(2017, 1,6))
]
```

500, 302, 550 etc... are my records. The next element are the date of those records. I would like to append them into a dictionary using a loop, but I always get an error of:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple.
```

Can anyone please give me some advise on how to append these into something like this:

```
myDict = {
    "record": "",
    "date": ""
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: ... foo = dict(query_results) ?

Comment: Do you want a list of dictionaries? Or a dictionary with the first element as key and the second as value?

Comment: I would like myDict = { "record": "302", "date": "somedate" }

Comment: and logs everything inside the dictionary

Comment: You might be using django wierly. How are you getting these results?

Comment: Probably a `values_list` query? I'd convert to a `values` query, that will return an iterable of dicts.

Answer (score 2):

You could unpack the list of tuples and zip them into a dict with the keys you want,

```
dict(zip(['record', 'date'], zip(*query_results)))
```

which outputs

```
{'date': (datetime.date(2017, 1, 1),
          datetime.date(2017, 1, 2),
          datetime.date(2017, 1, 3),
          datetime.date(2017, 1, 4),
          datetime.date(2017, 1, 5),
          datetime.date(2017, 1, 6)),
 'record': (500, 302, 550, 180, 645, 465)}
```

**Update**

If you're hoping for a list of dicts, you could use a list comprehension directly.

```
[dict(record=record, date=date) for record, date in query_results]
```

which outputs

```
[{'date': datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 'record': 500},
 {'date': datetime.date(2017, 1, 2), 'record': 302},
 {'date': datetime.date(2017, 1, 3), 'record': 550},
 {'date': datetime.date(2017, 1, 4), 'record': 180},
 {'date': datetime.date(2017, 1, 5), 'record': 645},
 {'date': datetime.date(2017, 1, 6), 'record': 465}]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much! I was able to unpack the tuples. Is there a way I can achieve something like this :

    mydict = {
        "record": 500,
        "date": 2017, 1, 1
    },{
        "record": 302,
        "date": 2017, 1, 2
    },{
        "record": 550,
        "date": 2017, 1, 3
    }

I am trying to achieve this because I am passing this distionary in my javascript later on. thanks  for your reply! Very mcuh appreciated

Comment: Thank you Mitch! This is what I needed. So much simple than I thought! :) thank again

Answer (score 0):

Alternative format to Mitch's answer, as the post was a bit ambiguous on wanted result:

```
>list_of_dicts = [ {'result': tup[0], 'date': tup[1]} for tup in query_results]

>list_of_dicts[0]    
{'result':500, 'date':datetime.date(2017, 1, 1) }
```

Building on other disucssion if you would rather have each record key to a date time you can instead build a dictionary of each record as an entry. This assumes that the records will never be duplicates. In which case the comprehension would look like this:

```
my_dict = {str(record) : date for record, date in query_results}
```

where the dict looks like:

```
{"500": date1, "501", date2} #but not necessarily in order
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop should do:

```
    my_dict = {}
    for item in query_results:
        my_dict[item[0]] = item[1]
```

This will stick your records (500, 550, etc.) as dictionary keys (item[0] part) so that you can easily call them out. And the value associated with those keys will be the datetime object (item[1] part).

If you want a more complicated solution please let us know.

Tom

Comment: Thank you very much tom! This is what I needed. I have been aiming for this. In my next step, how can I name the records records?  like this..
 mydict = { "record": 500, "date": 2017, 1, 1 },{ "record": 302, "date": 2017, 1, 2 },{ "record": 550, "date": 2017, 1, 3 } I think it will be easier to refer to this later on if I do this format.

Comment: @Marvin what do you mean by name the records? Record is a field in the dictionary. Do you mean to have a dictionary of dictionaries? Then you could have an identifier for each.

Comment: If you are using a dictionary each keyname must be unique and associating a new value to the existing key replaces the old value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them as a tuple inside the dictionary, Mitch's answer would work.

If you want a separate dictionary in each loop, you can do:

```
for result in query_results:
    myDict = {}
    myDict["record"] = result[0]
    myDict["date"] = result[1]
    your_operation()
```

Or if you want the record as the key, and the date as the value (unless you have repeating records, this could be very useful) you can do:

```
myDict = {}
for result in query_results:
    myDict[result[0]] = result[1]
```

Then you would have:

```
myDict = {"500": datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 
          "302": datetime.date(2017, 1, 2), 
          etc..}
```